# Oracle: Creating user which has all permissions on his/her own schema

Tags: oracle, permissions

I want to create a new Oracle Database user (running 12c here) and grant him/her all permissions so that he/she can do everything with his/her own schema (and his/her own schema **only**). What kind of permission/roles are suited best in order to get such a "default set" of permissions?

Background:

This user should be used for creating a Ruby on Rails application (i.e. the credentials that go into `config/database.yml`) and of course, I do not want to put `SYS` or `SYSTEM` in there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small list to get you started. Add more when the need is there.

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO &2 
/
GRANT ALTER SESSION TO &2 
/
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO &2 
/ 
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO &2
/
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO &2
/ 
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO &2 
/ 
GRANT GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS TO &2 
/
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO &2 
/ 
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO &2 
/
GRANT CREATE DATABASE LINK TO &2
/
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO &2
/
```

Comment: If you are in 12c, then you might want to look at granting quota on the user's default tablespace as well.